# django: Unable to get sorl-thumbnail working

Tags: python, django, sorl-thumbnail, podman

I am making a django site where users can upload images and I want to use sorl-thumbnail for thumbnail generation and caching.  I am using a container based workflow using podman on a fedora silverblue host.

I have setup a memcached cache engine (using the memcached docker image), and can set and get values to and from the cache in django-shell with no issues.  I have run the migrate command with sorl-thumbnail added to my installed-apps.  I have run the ./manage.py createcachetable command and no errors.  I am using pylibmc with:

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.PyLibMCCache',
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }
}
```

I have created a model which has the sorl.thumbnail ImageField, although I hope to use a standard imagefield eventually, which I believe is possible.

I have the following model, view, and template:

model...

```
class Image(models.Model):
    image_file = ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
    #thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to=str(user_directory_path) + '_thumb', null=True)
    userprofile = models.ForeignKey(ForumProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="images")
```

view...(the get function is added during debugging this issue)...

```py
class ForumProfileUploadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormView):
    form_class = ImageForm
    template_name = 'list.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('my-view')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class()
        message = 'Hi!'
        images = Image.objects.all()
        context = {'images': images, 'form': form, 'message': message}
        return render(self.request, 'list.html', context)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.userprofile = self.request.user.profile.forumprofile
        # img = PillowImage.open(obj.image_file.file)
        # obj.thumbnail = MakeThumbnail(self.request.FILES['image_file'])
        # breakpoint()
        obj.save()
        message = 'Success!'
        images = Image.objects.all()
        breakpoint()
        context = {'images': images, 'form': form, 'message': message}
        return render(self.request, 'list.html', context)

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        message = 'The form is not valid. Fix the following error:'
        images = Image.objects.all()
        context = {'images': images, 'form': form, 'message': message}
        return render(self.request, 'list.html', context)
```

template...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>

        <!-- List of uploaded documents -->
    {% block content %}
        {% load thumbnail %}
        {% if images %}
            All images in the database:
                {% for image in images %}
                        {% thumbnail image.image_file.url "100x100" as im %}
                            <img src="{{ im.url }}" width="{{ im.width }}" height="{{ im.height }}">
                        {% endthumbnail %}
                {% endfor %}
        {% else %}
            <p>No images.</p>
        {% endif %}

        <!-- Upload form. Note enctype attribute! -->
        <form action="{% url 'my-view' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ message }}
            <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>

            <p>{{ form.image_file.label_tag }} {{ form.image_file.help_text }}</p>

            <p>
                {{ form.image_file.errors }}
                {{ form.image_file }}
            </p>

            <p><input type="submit" value="Upload"/></p>
        </form>
    {% endblock content %}
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to get it working.  I am fairly certain that the necessary thing was for me to set the cache to work for the entire site, although I could have used it for a specific view, and this allowed sorl.thumbnail to start working.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/cache/#the-per-site-cache